# How do I send a GraphicsContext from a client to a server and then to all of the other clients?

Tags: java, networking, javafx

I'm now running into a problem with the input and output streams. It won't convert the socket input stream into a byte[] or the socket output stream into an int. How would get the program to actually send the byte[] array to the server? Here's the updated code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.canvas.Canvas;
import javafx.scene.canvas.GraphicsContext;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import javafx.embed.swing.SwingFXUtils;
import javafx.scene.image.*;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

public class PaintClient extends Application {
  //GUI components
  private TextField tfRed = new TextField("");
  private TextField tfGreen = new TextField("");
  private TextField tfBlue = new TextField("");
  private Button btSetColor = new Button("Set Color");
  private Button btReset = new Button("Reset");
  private Button btSend = new Button("Send");
  //Networking components
  private Socket socket;
  private ByteArrayOutputStream byteOut;
  private ByteArrayInputStream byteIn;

  @Override
  public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

    tfRed.setPrefWidth(80);
    tfGreen.setPrefWidth(80);
    tfBlue.setPrefWidth(80);

    GridPane gridPane = new GridPane();
    gridPane.add(new Label("Color"), 0, 0);
    gridPane.add(tfRed, 1, 0);
    gridPane.add(tfGreen, 2, 0);
    gridPane.add(tfBlue, 3, 0);
    gridPane.add(btSetColor, 4, 0);
    gridPane.add(btReset, 2, 1);
    gridPane.add(btSend, 3, 1);

    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(365,375);
    final GraphicsContext gc = canvas.getGraphicsContext2D();
    initDraw(gc);

    BorderPane bPane = new BorderPane();
    bPane.setTop(gridPane);
    bPane.setCenter(canvas);

    Scene scene = new Scene(bPane, 375, 450);
    primaryStage.setTitle("Drawing Canvas");
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();

    canvas.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED,
        new EventHandler<MouseEvent>(){

        @Override
        public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
            gc.beginPath();
            gc.moveTo(event.getX(), event.getY());
            gc.stroke();
        }
    });
    canvas.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DRAGGED,
        new EventHandler<MouseEvent>(){

        @Override
        public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
            gc.lineTo(event.getX(), event.getY());
            gc.stroke();
        }
    });


    //Networking
    try {
        socket = new Socket("localhost", 8000);
        byteIn = new ByteArrayInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
        byteOut = new ByteArrayOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        new Thread(() -> run()).start();
    }
    catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

  public void run(){
     while(true) {
        /*try {

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }*/
     }
  }

  public void process (Canvas canvas) {
     try {
        WritableImage image = canvas.snapshot(null, null);
        BufferedImage bImage = SwingFXUtils.fromFXImage(image, null);
        ImageIO.write(bImage, "jpg", byteOut);
        byteOut.flush();
        byte[] byteImage = byteOut.toByteArray();
        byteOut.close();
        byteOut.write(byteImage);
      } catch (IOException ex) {
          System.err.println(ex);
     }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Application.launch(args);
  }

  private void initDraw(GraphicsContext gc) {
        double canvasWidth = gc.getCanvas().getWidth();
        double canvasHeight = gc.getCanvas().getHeight();

        //Event handler when set color button is clicked
        btSetColor.setOnAction(e -> {
            if(!(tfRed.getText().trim().isEmpty()) && !(tfGreen.getText().trim().isEmpty()) &&
                !(tfBlue.getText().trim().isEmpty())) {
                int red = Integer.parseInt(tfRed.getText());
                int green = Integer.parseInt(tfGreen.getText());
                int blue = Integer.parseInt(tfBlue.getText());
                gc.setStroke(Color.rgb(red, green, blue));
            }
        });

        gc.setLineWidth(5);
        gc.fill();
        gc.strokeRect(
            0,              //x of the upper left corner of the drawing area
            0,              //y of the upper left corner of the drawing area
            canvasWidth,    //width of the drawing area
            canvasHeight);  //height of the drawing area
        gc.setLineWidth(1);

        //Event handler when reset button is clicked
        btReset.setOnAction(e -> {
            gc.clearRect(5, 5, 355, 365);
        });
  }
}
```

Comment: *EDIT* --- I don't need the GraphicsContext to be added onto whatever the other clients have in their GraphicsContexts, just to have the GraphicsContext replace the other ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sending `GraphicsContext` directly is not possible, as `GraphicsContext` is not explicitly `Serializable`. Typical ways of achieving what you intend are given below.

A. Remember user actions as "commands" and send them to the server / other clients. The commands will be executed on the client side and you will have the same rendered view. As example of implementation, you can wrap `GraphicsContext` API with your own that creates those commands.

```
public void fillOvalX(double x, double y, double w, double h) {
    // a possible approach
    commands.put(new DrawCommand(Type.FILL_OVAL, x, y, w, h));
    g.fillOval(x, y, w, h);
}
```

B. Perform a snapshot of the `GraphicsContext` into a JavaFX `Image` by calling [snapshot()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#snapshot-javafx.util.Callback-javafx.scene.SnapshotParameters-javafx.scene.image.WritableImage-). Then convert it into a `BufferedImage` using [SwingFXUtils](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/embed/swing/SwingFXUtils.html#fromFXImage-javafx.scene.image.Image-java.awt.image.BufferedImage-) and finally to `byte[]` using [ImageIO](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html#write-java.awt.image.RenderedImage-java.lang.String-java.io.OutputStream-) and `ByteArrayOutputStream`. The array `byte[]` can then be serialized over network. At the other end of the connection you will need to perform same operations in the opposite order. The links provide with sufficient information to do that.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the feedback. I was looking into snapshot() and the ByteArrayStreams after I originally posted here. I'll make an attempt at this soon.

Comment: I've edited the code to show where I am stuck now. The problem I have is stated in the edit.